# Why does the value become a string after each function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, search, foreach

I want to create a search function by using jQuery. When I like to search the target, why the result becomes a string instead of divided value? For example, there are AAA, BBB, CCC, and abc, and I want to search for AAA, but the `displayValue` shows 'AAABBBCCCabc'. Thank you!

```js
  $(".stream_navbar__search_form_input").on("keyup", () => {
    const inputValue = $(".stream_navbar__search_form_input").val();
    console.log(inputValue)
    $(".stream-body__streamer--name").each(() => {
      let displayName = $(".stream-body__streamer--name").text();
      console.log(displayName)
      if (displayName.indexOf(inputValue) != -1) {
        $(".stream-body__streamer--name").parent().parent().parent().show();
      } else {
        $(".stream-body__streamer--name").parent().parent().parent().hide();
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 stream_navbar__search_form">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 stream_navbar__search_form_input" type="text" placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Search</button>
        </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-md-4 stream-container">
      <div class="stream card">
        <div class="stream-body card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <h5 class="stream-body__streamer--name">BBB</h5>
          <p class="stream-body__viewer_count"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-md-4 stream-container">
      <div class="stream card">
        <div class="stream-body card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <h5 class="stream-body__streamer--name">CCC</h5>
          <p class="stream-body__viewer_count"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-md-4 stream-container">
      <div class="stream card">
        <div class="stream-body card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <h5 class="stream-body__streamer--name">abc</h5>
          <p class="stream-body__viewer_count"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-12 col-md-4 stream-container">
      <div class="stream card">
        <div class="stream-body card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <h5 class="stream-body__streamer--name">AAA</h5>
          <p class="stream-body__viewer_count"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code reads as "for each entry, get the text of all entries". Did you mean `$(this)` inside the loop?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, yes, I tries $(this), but got the same result...

Comment: You need a normal function to use `$(this)` within the callback. Or you can just use the second callback parameter that will give you each item. As it stands `$(".stream-body__streamer--name").text();` is going to give you *all* the text.

Comment: I am confused that why I can not use `$(".stream-body__streamer--name")`. Is `$(this)` not equal to `$(".stream-body__streamer--name")`?